# Query huge table fast based on timezone

Tags: mysql, performance

I need to query a table that has `1,852,789,683` rows which is `179.3GB` in size in the fastest way possible. My conditions are it needs to be a whole day (24hrs) Japan time.

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) CNT
  FROM info_table
 WHERE DATE(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, '+00:00', '+09:00')) = 20141216;
```

I have left it running for almost an hour now but it's still not done. Any advice?

DESCRIBE:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  info_table  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1793315059  Using where
```

Comment: Do you have any index ?

Comment: Is this a side effect of the timezone conversion (I wouldn't expect so; but you might check by running the query without conversion) or the query itself? Is there an index on the `created_at` column?

Comment: Performance based questions need - table structure so we can see indexes. Output of `EXPLAIN` if possible. Configuration of the storage engine used. Hardware. You provided none of these, and your query will inspect every record, convert it and compare to something that's not even a valid date format. The fastest way possible is to make use of an index for range scan. Seeing there's 0 information on any sort of table structure, it cannot be done until you provide us with required info.

Comment: @N.B. - all important and valid questions, but to the last point, that is the integer value that MySQL stores dates in natively.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea - good to know, I'll leave the comment in anyway, thanks for correction.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is going to evaluate that function on the `created_at` column for every flipping row in the table; that's a full scan.

To enable MySQL to do an efficient range scan operation on an index, you need to reference the bare column in the predicate, and you need an index with a leading column of `created_at`, and the query needs to be of the form:

```
WHERE created_at >=  val1
  AND created_at <   val2
```

The trick will be developing val1 and val2, the expressions that return the upper and lower bounds for the timestamp.

---

if we know:

```
  DATE(CONVERT_TZ(created_at, '+00:00', '+09:00')) = 20141216
```

then we know:

```
     CONVERT_TZ(created_at, '+00:00', '+09:00')) >= '2014-12-16'
 AND CONVERT_TZ(created_at, '+00:00', '+09:00')) <  '2014-12-17'
```

and (maybe?)...

```
     created_at >= CONVERT_TZ('2014-12-16','+09:00','+00:00')
 AND created_at <  CONVERT_TZ('2014-12-17','+09:00','+00:00')
```

I'm not sure about the behavior if the `CONVERT_TZ` function, whether the inversion is equivalent for all values in your case. Again, the "trick" will be getting the expressions that return the upper and lower bounds of your timestamp.

---

In our environment, we use GMT for all date, datetime and timestamp in the database; we use GMT for the database connections. The application layer does the appropriate timezone conversions. When I have a need to do something like you're doing, I'd be inclined to write something like this:

```
     created_at >= '2014-12-16' + INTERVAL   -9 HOUR
 AND created_at <  '2014-12-16' + INTERVAL 24-9 HOUR
```

Answer (score 1):

You  should create the statement so that it takes advantage of an index and then create  the index if you need to run this often. With  a table so large it may take some time to create the index. To use and index you can rewrite the statement as:

```
select count(*) cnt
from info_table
where created_at >=  '2014-12-16' and created_at<  '2014-12-17'
```

Even without and  index the above may run a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

The issues is that you are converting each row-value before it gets checked.  Change that to the other side

```
SELECT COUNT(*) CNT
FROM info_table
WHERE created_at = YourConvertedTimeZoneDateValue
```